# Rotating background image opposite to direction of div

Tags: html, css, css-animations, codepen

**Question [Resolved]:** How do I rotate the background image of a circle?

**Link**: https://codepen.io/Refath/pen/XaoMEj

Hi, I'm trying to rotate the background image of a circle element the opposite direction, but at the same magnitude of rotation, so that the background remains straight relative to the user. 
I've tried to use css keyframes, but realized this would not be the best idea, and then tried to implement the solution given [here][1], also failing after some tweaks. Thanks; Any help is appreciated (I'm not an advanced web developer, so I don't have much experience with JS, etc.)

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:500');
body {
  background-image: url(http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cynjeO46IAM/UBUmNk0NnxI/AAAAAAAAAqg/jpqpb_LMn6U/s1600/tR2hW.jpg);
}

.circle,
.r1c,
.r2c,
.r3c,
.r4c {
  border: white 2px solid;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  fill: lightred;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: -5px -5px;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.circle {
  background-image: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/Ry0QlB6DwmCZO/giphy.gif);
  background-position: -9px -9px;
}

.r1c:hover,
.r2c:hover,
.r3c:hover,
.r4c:hover {
  width: 108px;
  height: 108px;
  border-radius: 108px;
  transition: 0.3s ease-in;
  background-size: 120px 120px;
  background-position: -5.4px -5.4px;
}

.r1c {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 200px;
  background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/xenatt/the-circle/512/App-Google-icon.png");
}

.r2c {
  top: -400px;
  background-image: url(https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2015/09/30/109354_media_512x512.png);
}

.r3c {
  left: 400px;
  background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png);
}

.r4c {
  right: 400px;
  background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mIeBLLu8xOi-1bPbtRO_HYb5d1VchJDLDH4hebMO7R-GNOfueGDtHCKgPWFjwyCAORQ=w300");
}

.r1l,
.r2l,
.r3l,
.r4l {
  border: white 1px solid;
  width: 0px;
  height: 90px;
  border-radius: 90px;
  fill: lightred;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}

.r1l {
  top: 200px;
}

.r2l {
  top: -200px;
}

.r3l {
  width: 90px;
  height: 0px;
  left: 200px;
}

.r4l {
  width: 90px;
  height: 0px;
  left: -200px;
}

.parent {
  top: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  animation: around 7.5s infinite ease;
}

@keyframes around {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  25% {
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  75% {
    transform: rotate(270deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.hero {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<center>
  <h1 class="hero">Hi, User!</h1>
</center>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="parent">

  <div class="circle">
  </div>

  <a href="https://www.google.com">
    <div class="r1c">
    </div>
  </a>

  <div class="r2c">
  </div>

  <div class="r3c">
  </div>

  <div class="r4c">
  </div>

  <div class="r1l">
  </div>

  <div class="r2l">
  </div>

  <div class="r3l">
  </div>

  <div class="r4l">
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem with the @keyframes....?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use it to solve this problem. As I've said, I'm relatively inexperienced. Plus, the problem of how I would rotate the background image still remains, even with keyframes.

Comment: You can try to apply the same animation in reverse. Like so `.r1c, .r2c, .r3c, .r4c {animation: around 7.5s infinite linear;
animation-direction:reverse}` [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vj4441nm/)

Comment: This might actually work, let me tweak it out a bit; Thanks

Comment: Wow this is great @Ihazkode, thanks!

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want something like this :

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:500');

body{
 background-color:black;
}
 img{
  position:relative;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  animation: around 6.5s infinite ease;
  animation-direction:reverse
 }


.circle, .r1c, .r2c, .r3c, .r4c{
 border: white 2px solid;
 width: 90px;
 height: 90px;
 border-radius: 90px;
 fill: lightred;
 
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 
 background-size: 100px 100px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: -5px -5px;

 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.circle{
 background-image: url(https://media.giphy.com/media/Ry0QlB6DwmCZO/giphy.gif);
 background-position: -9px -9px;
}

.r1c:hover, .r2c:hover, .r3c:hover, .r4c:hover{
 width:108px;
 height: 108px;
 border-radius:108px;
 transition: 0.3s ease-in;
 background-size: 120px 120px;
 background-position: -5.4px -5.4px;
}

.r1c{ 
 position: relative;
 overflow: hidden;
 
 top: 310px;
 background-image: url("http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/xenatt/the-circle/512/App-Google-icon.png");
}

.r2c{
 top: -400px;
 background-image: url(https://www.shareicon.net/data/512x512/2015/09/30/109354_media_512x512.png);
}

.r3c{
 left: 400px;
 background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/c/c2/F_icon.svg/2000px-F_icon.svg.png);
}

.r4c{
 right: 400px;
 background-image: url("https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/mIeBLLu8xOi-1bPbtRO_HYb5d1VchJDLDH4hebMO7R-GNOfueGDtHCKgPWFjwyCAORQ=w300");
}

.r1l, .r2l, .r3l, .r4l{
 border: white 1px solid;
 width: 0px;
 height: 90px;
 border-radius: 90px;
 fill: lightred;
 
 position: absolute;
 margin: auto;
 
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
}

.r1l{
 top: 200px;
}
.r2l{
 top: -200px;
}

.r3l{
 width: 90px;
 height: 0px;
 
 left: 200px;
}

.r4l{
 width: 90px;
 height: 0px;
 
 left: -200px;
}

.parent {
 
 top: 0px;
 bottom: 0px;
 left: 0px;
 right: 0px;
 position:absolute;
 animation: around 7.5s infinite ease;
}

@keyframes around{
 0% {transform: rotate(0deg);}
 25% {transform: rotate(90deg);}
 
 25% {transform: rotate(90deg);}
 50% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
 
 50% {transform: rotate(180deg);}
 75% {transform: rotate(270deg);}
 
 75% {transform: rotate(270deg);}
 100% {transform: rotate(360deg);}
 }

.hero{
 color:white;
 font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<img src='http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cynjeO46IAM/UBUmNk0NnxI/AAAAAAAAAqg/jpqpb_LMn6U/s1600/tR2hW.jpg'/>
<center> <h1 class = "hero">Hi, User!</h1></center>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><div class = "parent">
 
<div class = "circle">
 </div>

<a href = "https://www.google.com"><div class = "r1c">
 </div></a>

<div class = "r2c">
 </div>

<div class = "r3c">
 </div>

<div class = "r4c">
 </div>

<div class = "r1l">
 </div>

<div class = "r2l">
 </div>

<div class = "r3l">
 </div>

<div class = "r4l">
 </div>
 
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response; It seems like making the animation go in reverse is actually working out.

Comment: Your Welcome @DarkRunner. Happy Coding.